# pandas change dtypes only columns of float64

Tags: python, pandas

I need to change the dtype of multiple columns (over 400) but the dataframe has different kind of dtypes. Some columns dtypes are `float64` whereas some columns' are `int64` or `object`:

```
print my_df.dtypes
```

**Output:**

```
x1                       int64
x2                       int64
x3                       object
x4                       float64
x5                       float64
x6                       float64
x7                       float64
...

x400                     object
x401                     object
x402                     object
...
```

I need to change all `int64` to `int8` or `int16` and also all `float64` to `float32`. I have tried below snippet, but it did not worked:

```
my_df[my_df.dtypes == np.int64].astype(np.int16)
my_df[my_df.dtypes == np.float64].astype(np.float32)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I find my way :)

Find the columns that have dtype of `float64`

```
cols = my_df.select_dtypes(include=[np.float64]).columns
```

Then change dtype only the `cols` of the dataframe.

```
my_df[cols] = my_df[cols].astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: You can also replace `np.float64` with `"float64"` to skip importing numpy if not already imported.

Answer (score 7):

You almost got it!

```
my_df.loc[:, my_df.dtypes == 'float64'] = my_df.loc[:, my_df.dtypes == 'float64'].astype('float32')
my_df.loc[:, my_df.dtypes == 'int64'] = my_df.loc[:, my_df.dtypes == 'int64'].astype('int32')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build a mapping dictionary and use `astype`

```
new_types = {np.dtype(np.int64): np.int16, 
             np.dtype(np.float64): np.float32}

df = df.astype(df.dtypes.map(new_types).to_dict())
```

---

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [1.0,2.0,3.0]})

    col1    col2
0   1       1.0
1   2       2.0
2   3       3.0

>>> df.dtypes

col1      int64
col2    float64
dtype: object
```

Then

```
df.dtypes.map({np.dtype(np.int64): np.int16, np.dtype(np.float64): np.float32}).to_dict()
```

Gives a dict of the new types

```
{'col1': numpy.int16, 'col2': numpy.float32}
```

Then just use `astype` with this dict

```
>>> df.astype(df.dtypes.map(new_types).to_dict())

col1      int16
col2    float32
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(5, dtype='int64'), 'b': np.arange(5, dtype='float64')})
```

Use [**`select_dtypes`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to get columns that match your desired type:

```
df.select_dtypes(np.float64) # or df.select_dtypes(np.float64).columns to save for casting

     b
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  2.0
3  3.0
4  4.0
```

And cast as needed.